# Cost of Unity Local Multiplayer VS Unity Online Multiplayer

Tags: unity, multiplayer, unity-networking, unet, photon

I know that making multiplayer games in Unity costs money because of the servers that are used in connecting the players. So basically its free upto 20 CCU and then it increases as per the CCU. Its true for the online multiplayer games.

But for local multiplayer games(LAN), should it cost the money for using it? Because we converted one of the devices in the local as the server and we don't need their servers. So am I thinking right ?? Or I am going wrong somewhere?

Just wanted to be clear about how to make a local multiplayer and ***not*** an online multiplayer.

Also wanted to ask if Photon supports local multiplayer?

Basically I am confused about how to make offline local multiplayer game.

Comment: "Local multiplayer" usually refers to games being played on a single machine — like splitscreen or shared screen games. We usually use the term LAN game to refer to games played over multiple machines on a local network. Have you tried working your way through some [Unity LAN game tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=unity+lan+game+tutorial) to get some starting points and practice the basics? Did you run into any particular snag we can help you with?

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did see the online multiplayer tuts but didn't understand how the same would work for LAN. As for online multiplayer you connect to the official servers that you rent but in the latter we make user as a server if required.. So didn't quite understand how the logic goes here. Will surely check the tutorials. Just had something in mind. Thanks again.

Comment: There shouldn't be any CCU costs for a LAN-only game.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about this too.. Should not be any CCU costs in LAN-only.